# How does Scrapy works on Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, scrapy, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to visualise the results from this code, using Scrapy:

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'test'
start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07Q6H83VY']

def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.css('div.review'):
        item = {}

        item['author'] = row.css('span.a-profile-name::text').extract_first()

        rating = row.css('i.review-rating > span::text').extract_first().strip().split(' ')[0]
        item['rating'] = int(float(rating.strip().replace(',', '.')))

        item['title'] = row.css('span.review-title > span::text').extract_first()
        created_date = row.css('span.review-date::text').extract_first().strip()
        item['created_date'] = created_date

        review_content = row.css('div.reviewText ::text').extract()
        review_content = [rc.strip() for rc in review_content if rc.strip()]
        item['content'] = ', '.join(review_content)

        yield item
```

Then

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(TestSpider)
process.start()
```

I am using Jupyter notebook. An example of output should be:

```
{
        "author": "Jhona Diaz",
        "rating": 4,
        "title": "Recomendable solo si eres fan ya que si está algo caro",
        "created_date": "Reviewed in Mexico on November 23, 2019",
        "content": "Buena calidad y pues muy completo"
    },
    {
        "author": "MANUEL MENDOZA OLVERA",
        "rating": 5,
        "title": "Perfecto Estado",
        "created_date": "Reviewed in Mexico on September 28, 2019",
        "content": "excelente, la edición es de caja  metálica y llegó intacta"
    },
```

Could you please tell me the steps for getting these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be write the output in a file to see the result which can be done by `pipeline` class like:

```py
import json

from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

class JsonWriterPipeline:

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('items.jl', 'w')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(ItemAdapter(item).asdict()) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

Then add you pipeline in custom setting of your spider:

```py
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     
     custom_settings = {
             'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.JsonWriterPipeline': 1}
         }
```

You can find more information about item pipeline in [Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).